# Yaml vscode plugin from red hat does not validate anything

Tags: yaml, vscode-extensions, jsonschema

I installed [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-yaml) in VSCode, created schema, reloaded and yes, I can see a line above my YAML files, telling me it sees and know the schema.

But... it does give me neither completion, nor error messages when I type things that do not exist in the schema.

[Here is](https://pastebin.com/yYaJv6HT) the shema.

It does not show me errors even on nonsense like this:

`my.yaml:`

```
wrong: value
another_wrong: value
  - hello
    lala
```

What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you for help!